# How to get all fields in a protobuf message?

Tags: protocol-buffers

I am using protobuf these days, and I have met a problem. 
I want to get all fields in a protobuf message and I know a method, use `field_count()` to get the field count of a message, and then use the function `FindFieldByNumber()` to get all of the fields. But， if the field number of a message is discontinuous, for example:

```
message MyPb
{
uint32    id   =1;
int32 score    =2;
string name    =5;
uint32  high   =6;
}
```

Then，the field count of MyPb is 4, and I use

```
for(int i=1; i<=count; ++i)
{
    descriptor->FindFieldByNumber(i);
}
```

where count=4.

using this method, can I get the field `name` and `high`?
If not, does somebody know a better method? 
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `descriptor->field(i)` instead of FindFieldByNumber(). Please check [the documentation for the difference between these two functions](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.descriptor#Descriptor.field.details).

Comment: Thank you very much, and your answer solved my problem.